# Reading from the screen and writing it to a file in python?

Tags: python, json, file, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am printing some string on the screen and later I want to read it to a file. I am failing in reading the string to a file. I am making a mistake here - filehandle.write(.read()) . can someone tell me ?

Comment: what is the error message? I can't imagine ".read()" is python synthax

Comment: `filehandle.write(.read())` is not a valid Python. Why do you think it should work? Start small e.g., try to write a word `"hello"` to screen and to a file. Do not go any further until you'll manage to do it.

Comment: File ".\Parsing_throug_folder_DEU.py", line 164, in <module>
    outfilename = filename(".txt")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Please post your code. It looks like you lack basic Python knowledge. What kind of method is filename? Python thinks it is a string.

Comment: @suni You're welcome! ... >:(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you need JSON for, but this is how to print a string and write it to a file in just python:

```
string = "text like hello world"
print(string)
f = open('fileaddress', 'w')
f.write(string)
```

Line 1: Set the string to "text like hello world"

Line 2: Print the string on the screen

Line 3: Opens the file for writing. Can also do 'r' instead of 'w' to open it it read mode. Read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html for help.

Line 4: Set the file's contents to the string that we declared.